# ajax to server and then to database in django project

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, mongodb

I am writing a code to take data from a form, send to server via ajax(.js file). I want to send the same data from server to database, here my database is mongo db.

ajax from .js file:

`function letsPostIt(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/gmaps',
        data: { location: data },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}`

Now I cannot write my views.py and models.py file in order to send the data from here to my database.

My current views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from registration.models import Value
from django.http import HttpResponse
def letsPostIt(request):
 post_text = request.POST.get('location')
 post = Value(text=post_text)
 post.save()
 return HttpResponse()
from registration.models import Value 
def gmaps(request):
 val = Value.objects.all()
 post=Value(text=val)
 post.save()
 return render(request, 'gmaps.html', {'values': val})
```

models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from mongoengine import *
class Value(models.Model):
     text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
def __str__(self):
 return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from registration import views as reg_views
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^gmaps/',reg_views.gmaps),
        url(r'^gmaps/pos/',reg_views.letsPostIt),
]
```

I am new to django and hence have a very less idea about the syntax and terms used.
I am not getting any error here but while making migrations, no changes are detected and the collection in database is not getting created with the values from user.
Any help in this would be really appreciated.

Comment: what doesn't work? in gmaps you have 2 returns why?

Comment: Before starting to create (relatively) complicated solutions like this, I recommend you complete first the Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I removed the last return with HttpResponse @madalinivascu

Comment: I have read and tried this tutorial  @skoll

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing querying with creating. `POST.objects.get()` - as the name implies - is for getting existing objects from the db.

To create a new post, you should instantiate it with the data you want, then save:

```
post = POST(text=post_text)
post.save()
```

As skill says in the comments, this is all fully explained in the tutorial.